# Migrate domain to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, elastic-beanstalk

I am planning to move an existing website to an Elastic Beanstalk environment. Currently the website is hosted on several ec2 instances which sit behind a HAProxy load balancer . The load balancer sits behind Nginx which handles ssl termination. All of the servers are not in a VPC.

So a basic schema of the hardware platform looks like this:

```
     NGinx - SSL termination
       |
     HAProxy - load balancing
       |
EC2 - EC2 - EC2 <-> RDS
       (non VPC)
```

The elastic beanstalk environment consists of an Elastic Load Balancer which also handles SSL and several EC2 instances for the application.

The new environment will connect to a new RDS instance (populated with the data from the old one) which sits in the same VPC.

When the migration will start I will modify the domain DNS to point to the EB environment host but this will leave a window in which the clients who have cached the DNS records will hit the old environment and the old database. To mitigate this I was thinking of configuring the HAProxy on the old environment to route the requests to the load balancer on the EB environment. But i'm not sure how to handle SSL configuration for this operation. Where should I configure the requests routing? In Nginx or HAproxy?

Has anybody did something similar?
Thanks

Comment: Just set a low (60 seconds) TTL a few weeks (or days/hours, depending on your current TTL) in advance, and be ready to put up a "scheduled maintenance" page on the old server during that 60 second cutover period. Infinitely easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the following config with haproxy to do SSL passthrough to AWS ESS

```
userlist elk_user_list
    user elk-user1 password PASS

global
    log 127.0.0.1 local2
    stats socket /var/run/haproxy.sock
    tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048


defaults
    log global
    mode http
    option httpchk GET /
    option log-health-checks
    option  dontlognull
    timeout connect 5000
    timeout client  50000
    timeout server  50000


resolvers dns
    nameserver public-0 172.23.16.2:53
    hold valid 15s


frontend elk-example-com
    # Ciphers list: https://weakdh.org/sysadmin.html
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/haproxy/elk.example.com.pem no-sslv3 npn http/1.1 ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA
    option httplog
    default_backend amazon-elk

    # require authentication
    acl auth_ok http_auth(elk_user_list)
    acl ipwhitelist src xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

    http-request allow if ipwhitelist
    http-request allow if auth_ok
    http-request auth realm 'Authorization required' unless ipwhitelist
    http-request deny


backend amazon-elk
    balance roundrobin
    option redispatch
    option forwardfor
    http-request del-header Authorization
    http-request set-header Host elk-production.us-west-1.es.amazonaws.com
    server site elk-production.us-west-1.es.amazonaws.com:443 resolvers dns check inter 1000 ssl ca-file /etc/ssl/haproxy/aws-ess-rootca.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

After some more research I found that I can configure HAProxy to do SSL passthrough by setting its operation mode to TCP instead of HTTP (frontend & backend) - this will stream the request to the ELB which will handle SSL offloading and pass the request further to the application servers.

Also I will have to take out NGinx since it will no longer be need it.

Comment: You can use http mode as well. We use haproxy to forward all requests to ESS